# iPad emulator suggestion

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, emulation

my employer is killing me.

I'm currently editing our website to fit on iPad's display, however I do not have an iPad. I have tried the desktop iPad emulator called airiPad made by adobe and the online www.ipad-emulator.org/

both are working but whenever my boss send me his screenshots from his iPad it looks very different so I'm asking advice and suggestion on what emulator can I use to get the most accurate results..

P.S All of our computer units are running on windows7.
thanks..

Comment: What about original iPad simulator on Mac? Maybe you need to refine your question to add OS and other restrictions.

Comment: @coverback sorry, i don't have a Mac nor does our office. All units are running on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying Safari under Windows, I suppose that's the best you can get on Windows.

The only thing you need from the simulator is its Webkit engine, and some 3rd party solutions hardly will deliver you the very same engine as the one on the Mac OS X or iOS.

Also, [here are some Apple's guidelines on compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html).